# What is the real difference between new vs Object.create()

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I am trying to understand the real difference between keywords `new` and `Object.create()`

**Explaination:**

- `a1` is `function` while `a2` is an `object`
- `a1` & `a2` are having `key1` as default property. `key2` is being assigned after an instance `bxx` is created from them. to check whether `bxx` is independent object itself or just a reference.

```js
"use strict";

function a1() {
  this.key1 = "value 1";
}

let a2 = {
  key1: "value 1"
};

let b1new, b1obj, b2new, b2obj;

try {
  b1obj = Object.create(a1);
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Error a1: ", e.message)
}
try {
  b1new = new a1();
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Error a1: ", e.message)
}


try {
  b2obj = Object.create(a2);
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Error a2: ", e.message)
}
try {
  b2new = new a2();
} catch (e) {
  console.error("Error a2: ", e.message)
}

//let b = new a();

a1.key2 = "value 2";
a2.key2 = "value 2";

if (b1obj) {
  console.log("b1obj.key1: ", b1obj.key1);
  console.log("b1obj.key2: ", b1obj.key2);
}
if (b1new) {
  console.log("b1new.key1: ", b1new.key1);
  console.log("b1new.key2: ", b1new.key2);
}
if (b2obj) {
  console.log("b2obj.key1: ", b2obj.key1);
  console.log("b2obj.key2: ", b2obj.key2);
}
if (b2new) {
  console.log("b2new.key1: ", b2new.key1);
  console.log("b2new.key2: ", b2new.key2);
}
```

Output:

```
"Error a2: " "a2 is not a constructor"    
"b1obj.key1: " undefined    
"b1obj.key2: " "value 2"    
"b1new.key1: " "value 1"    
"b1new.key2: " undefined    
"b2obj.key1: " "value 1"    
"b2obj.key2: " "value 2"
```

**Questions:**

1. Why can't use `new` on a2 ?
2. Why `b1obj.key1` is `undefined` ?
3. Why `b2obj.key2` is still referring to parent's property?

Comment: you can use ``new`` on classes, like ``function ClassName(){}``, when ``a2`` it's just a variable

Comment: The object used in Object.create actually forms the prototype of the new object, where as in the new Function() form the declared properties/functions do not form the prototype.

Comment: It might have been easier to ask 1 question at a time, or at least split your Snippets into separate ones with just the problems your asking.  Anyway, `new` and `Object.create` are not the same.  There is a massive difference.

Comment: @Keith wow what a great suggestion and explanation. so according to your suggestion i should create 3 questions with pasting a same block of code and guess what; i should get an answer that 'There is a massive difference, but don't know what'?

Comment: @AmitShah  Yes, because currently your question requires me scrolling up & down, constantly to find out what your talking about.  Would have been really nice if each question & snippet, and results were together.  It just makes it easier for people to help. eg. First question, I had to find out were you defined a2, and then when you called new, and of course the question itself,  IOW: 3 places up & down, for 1 question.  And to top this off, there was another 2 questions.  Hope that makes sense, not having a go, but for me your question was hard to answer just because of it's layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `new` can be used only with a function or a class. 
   When a function is executed as `new User(...)`, it does the following steps:

   - A new empty object is created and assigned to `this`.
   - The function body executes. Usually it modifies `this`, adds new properties to it.
   - If there is no explicit `return` statement, the value of `this` is returned.

---

2. `b1obj.key1` is `undefined` because `Object.create` first parameter is an object wich becomes a prototype of created object. In this case it is the `a1` function, which doesn't have a `key1` property assigned, it only assignes `key1` to its `this` when called.

---

3. `b2obj` has the `a2` object as its prototype, so it has access to its `key2` property

**Suming up:** while `new` keyword is more often used to create new instances of objects from an existing 'template', `Object.create` is more flexible and allows you to work with a prototype, create property descriptors. For example, you can create a shallow copy of object:

```
let clone = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj), 
                          Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj));
```

I suggest you to read [this](https://javascript.info/constructor-new) article about `new` keyword and [this](https://javascript.info/prototype-methods) one about `Object.create` and other prototype methods.

**UPDATE** (about the relationship between object and its prototype):
Once you have created a new object, changing its properties does not affect the prototype. For example,

```
let a2 = {
    key2: "some text"
};
let b2 = Object.create(a2);
a2.key2 = "I am a2";
b2.key2 = "I am b2";

alert(a2.key2 + ", " + b2.key2);
```

will alert `I am a2, I am b2`. That's because `b2` has its own `key2` property. But If it doesn't, JavaScript will look for it in its prototype. You can find a detailed description of the prototype inheritance [here](https://javascript.info/prototype-inheritance)

Comment: `Object.create()` is also useful in polyfilling things like ES6 classes: `class A extends B {}` -> `function A() {}; A.prototype = Object.create(B.prototype, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(A));`

Comment: Thanks, I found this answer a bit nearer to my query after going through the provided links. Basically I understood the difference. Now in further process to find another related answer for the post instance/object creation; what happens with the original/child object if we change their properties vise verse.. but for that i will create new post. May be before that if you can provide some helpful links?

Comment: @Amit I've added some information about inheritance. If the answer was useful, please accept it

Answer (score 2):

Please see following answers.

> 1. Why can't use new on a2 ?

Because `new` keyword can only be used with `constructors/classes`. In Javascript `functions` can be used as `constructors`. And `a2` is an `Object`

> 2. Why b1obj.key1 is undefined ?

Since you haven't used `new` keyword for `a1`, instance will not be created and you won't be able to use `properties` defined in `this`. And `Object.create()` will create an empty object with its prototype set to `a1` as `object` not `function` (`function` can also be treated as `objects` in JavaScript)

> 3. Why b2obj.key2 is still referring to parent's property?

Because you haven't overridden it.

> What is the real difference between new vs Object.create()

`new` is used for `constructor` functions and `Object.create()` is used to inherit `Objects`. Also, `Object.create()` can be used with `functions`, but then `function` will act like normal `object` and not `constructor`.

Comment: 1. so can't i use `a2.prototype = {constructor: function(){}}` something like this then can i use new on a2? I think No, so the question is what is the form of constructor when it's not visible. where is it actually? 

So overall; The `new` will return a copy of object executing the constructor. while 'Object.create` will just give a new pointer of the object referring to same object.

then what happens if i add new lines `a1.prototype.key1 = "value 1 new";
    a1.prototype.key2 = "value 2 new";` just above `a1.key2 = "value 2";    
    a2.key2 = "value 2";`